# How to place a DIV in the bottom of the first page in print mode using html and css bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want the output to be something like this. I tried to make the `<div>` element `position: absolute` but it pushed all the way down to the last page.

Instead I want to accomplish this without using any PDF libraries.

[image]

Comment: use 12 system grid!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

many different ways to do this.  Here are two.  The first uses flexbox and the second uses absolute positioning.

answer updated.

```css
.container2{
display:flex;
height:100vh;
width:100vw;
justify-content:center;

}

#page4{
background:pink;
position:relative;
}

#bottom2{
position:absolute;
height:20vh;
width:30vw;
left:calc(50vw - 30vw/2 + 10vw);
background:purple;
top:calc(100vh - 20vh);
}

#content{
height:35vh;
width:80vw;
background:white;
margin-top:10vh;

}
```

```html
<div class='container2' id='page4'>
<div id='content'>
</div>
<div id='bottom2'></div>

</div>
<div class='container2' id='page5'>

</div>
<div class='container2' id='page6'>
</div>
```

Comment: i need the content of the page 1 to be in that position, also the bottom div ust be a slightly on the right too. thanks btw